# Perfomance issue with rake task: Would adding worker dyno resolve the issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake-task, mailer

In our application we are using rake task for sending mails to around 11 000 users. Each email sending is executed as a delayed job as given following.

```
@Users.each do |a|
    a.delay.send_email(body,text)
end
```

It was working perfect two weeks back and suddenly slowed down. Means it was about to send all that emails in single day but currently it takes time.

We have tried to follow this performance issue but couldn't find anything so far.
1. We investigated the code, tried with single delayed job. Commented out the part taking from db etc. But it is doing in the same time
2. Tried the email sending part commented out. But time taken was same to execute the delayed job.

Later on noticed about the heroku worker process dyno. We have purchased 1 Worker and 2 Webs currently. Is that the reason it is getting delayed. If so how it was previously working? Adding more workers would increase the performance?